# How to show YTD last year vs Same period this year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

i have this query that is showing me the same period of days from this month 2016 and the same month 2015,

But i need to show YTD

Ene, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, up to Jul 6 2015 and same period 2016 (because today is the 6th and tomorrow show 7th then 8th july and so on) Meaning that is something similar to the code i have but instead of showing me just the current month i need YTD.

```
SELECT        OrderStatus, Sum_SellPrice, Sum_SellerMargin, Sum_BuyPrice, OrderDate
FROM            Sum_OrderCharges
WHERE        (OrderStatus IN ('Completed', 'Invoiced', 'Open')) 
AND (OrderPeriodYear IN ('2015','2016')) 
AND (MONTH(OrderDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())) 
and (day(OrderDate) <= DAY(GETDATE())) 
ORDER BY OrderDate
```

Comment: `AND (MONTH(OrderDate) <= MONTH(GETDATE()))`?

Comment: @PeterVandivier That won't quite work because of the `day` portion.  If the day is the 15th, only the 1st-15th will be pulled for previous months.

Comment: you might want to do this..
  select to_char(trunc(sysdate),'YYYYMMDD') as ytd from dual;
  select to_char(trunc(sysdate),'YYYYMMDD')-10000 as ytd from dual;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `OR` statement to cover for this:

`OR MONTH(OrderDate) <= MONTH(GETDATE())`

```
SELECT OrderStatus, Sum_SellPrice, Sum_SellerMargin, Sum_BuyPrice, OrderDate
FROM   Sum_OrderCharges
WHERE  OrderStatus IN ('Completed', 'Invoiced', 'Open') 
AND OrderPeriodYear IN ('2015','2016')
AND ( (MONTH(OrderDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND day(OrderDate) <= DAY(GETDATE()))
    OR MONTH(OrderDate) <= MONTH(GETDATE())  )--Be sure to wrap the entire OR segment with ()
ORDER BY OrderDate
```

Comment: beat me to it I got sidetracked with another answer :)  Only 1 comment I would wrap MONTH(OrderDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
AND day(OrderDate) <= DAY(GETDATE()) in parenthesis so that the AND/OR logic on the month/day is clear.  AND has precedence in SQL but my personal preference is always to establish precedence by parenthesis

Comment: @Matt I tried to leave it but wasn't sure if you were rewriting or not.^^  I have the `AND..OR` wrapped, though it is difficult to see with all of the parenthesis.

Comment: No worries Arron Glad you helped. you have the entire and or wrapped but I would recommend also wrapping the first AND part.  That way it separates both sides of the OR condition. do like this:   AND ((MONTH(OrderDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
AND day(OrderDate) <= DAY(GETDATE())) 
OR MONTH(OrderDate) <= MONTH(GETDATE()))

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for your help but this still show me all the month of july of 2015, i need to show only the days that had passed in 2016 for 2015 meaning that it should show 6 days of july 2015.

Comment: @AbleTech Oh, change it to `OR MONTH(OrderDate) < MONTH(GETDATE())`.  Just `<` instead of `<=`

Comment: Thank very much sir. @AaronD

Answer (score 0):

It is more elegant to prepare and use date windows using CTE. This is an example.

```
declare @start as date='2016-01-01', @end date=getdate(),@depth int = 2

;with dates as (--prepare date ranges
--anchor query
select @start startDate, @end endDate, 1 cnt
union all
--recursive query 
select dateadd(year,-1,startDate),dateadd(year,-1,endDate), cnt+1
from dates where cnt < @depth
)
select d.startDate,d.endDate, 
OrderStatus, Sum_SellPrice, Sum_SellerMargin, Sum_BuyPrice --aggregate if necessary
from Sum_OrderCharges o
inner join dates d on o.OrderDate between d.startDate and d.endDate
WHERE (OrderStatus IN ('Completed', 'Invoiced', 'Open'))
```

This way you can even compare date ranges, for example 2015-11-01 to 2016-07-05 and 2014-11-01 to 2015-07-05.